# CMake trying to build my first library (of gtest)

Tags: cmake

I am playing around with producing my own libraries to save some compile time. To start easy, it thought to begin to pack gtest/gmock in a library. I am now at the point where I would like to publish the headers of gtest/gmock along side with the library archive itself. At least, I think this is the logical way of providing libraries? So that users of the library (which is only me in this case, but just for the idea ;-)) can add the library and can find the publich headers to use the library, next to library.

So I now have this little cmake file (see below), which produces the library. I already gave it a test spin, it works. But, I was expecting to find all headers exported to the `../lib` folder as well, but that doesn't happen.

Who can help me out?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1...3.22)

project(gtest)

set(COMPILER_DIRECTIVES    "-O0 -g3 -Wall -MMD -MP")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS        "${COMPILER_DIRECTIVES}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "")

set(SOURCE                  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

# Overrides
#set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE          ON)

set(gtest_headers
    ${SOURCE}/googlemock
    ${SOURCE}/googlemock/include
    ${SOURCE}/googletest
    ${SOURCE}/googletest/include
)

include_directories(
    ${gtest_headers}
)

# Source files

file(GLOB_RECURSE googletest_sources CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
    ${SOURCE}/googlemock/src/*.cc
    ${SOURCE}/googletest/src/*.cc
)
list (REMOVE_ITEM googletest_sources
    ${SOURCE}/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
    ${SOURCE}/googlemock/src/gmock-all.cc
    ${SOURCE}/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${googletest_sources})
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_20)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        ${gtest_headers}
)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../lib"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../lib"
    OUTPUT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}
)
```

Comment: Publishing a library is performed via **installaing** it or via packaging, CMake documentation suggest a nice guide about installing: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Installing%20and%20Testing.html

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev,thx for replying. Will read through.